# Singleton computed property in swift 3

Tags: ios, swift, computed-properties

I am trying to achieve a singleton UIView instance in my code, so whenever I create an instance of 'MyView' the nib file will load for only once and then reuse it again:

```
class MyView : UIView {

    @IBOutlet weak var someLabel: UILabel!
    
    static var customeView : UIView = {

        let view = Bundle.main.loadNibNamed(String(describing: MyView.self), owner: self, options: nil)?[0] as! UIView
        return view
    }()
    
    convenience init() {
        
        self.init(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 576, height: 30))
        
        let viewForOnce = MyView.customeView
        viewForOnce.frame = bounds
    }
}
```

The problem is that whenever I call the `MyView.customeView` it get crashed saying that 'this class is not key value coding-compliant', I think this is happening because of the 'owner: self' inside the computed property.

Any help will be appreciated.

[image]

Comment: `this class is not key value coding-compliant` is normally an Interface Builder issue, you can use `self` in a lazy initialized property

Comment: I double check this one particularly and everything is connected! I double check this one particularly and everything is connected! but If I put owner: MyView () instead of owner: self then it will work!

Comment: Why do you actually need this behavior? Why not adding `ReceiptView` in MyView class? Btw, what you're doing has nothing to do with singleton pattern.

Comment: I meant with the singleton is loading the nib only once whenever I create and instance of that class.
ReceiptView is by mistake its MyView now.

Answer (score 1):

The issue is most probably with your `ReceiptView.xib`. You should review it first. 
Look for an `IBOutlet`, which is there in a xib, but not in your ReceiptView class and delete it.

**Edit:**

> I meant with the singleton is loading the nib only once whenever I
>   create and instance of that class.

1. No, this is not going to work like that. Every time init is called, your computed property is also called and a new instance is created from xib every time.
2. As *Carien van Zyl* already mentioned, you are using `self` in a `class` var which **corresponds to `MyView` class itself** (or it's subclass if its called for a subclass), **not an instance**. Try passing `nil` as `owner` instead.
3. The whole technique is looking wrong to me. You should not use singleton pattern with `UIView` subclasses. 
   There is nothing wrong in calling `loadNibNamed` multiple times and create exactly the same instances. If you want to use the same instance multiple times in a view hierarchy, it's not possible since every view can have only one superview. In this case you should follow MVC pattern: create multiple `MyView` instances -> update model whenever you change something in a view and want those changes to be reflected elsewhere -> update another view using updated model.

Comment: I double check this one particularly and everything is connected! but If I put owner: MyView () instead of owner: self then it will work!

Answer (score 0):

`customeView` is a type property.  Therefor, self inside of it, will reference `MyView.self` which is a class type.  The class type do not hold the instance variables, which includes `someLabel`.

See [Apple's documentation on Types](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Types.html)